# Android: Google package broken URL

Tags: facebook, google-play, facebook-apps, facebook-authentication

I want to active Live Mode on Facebook APP ID but I [image]

The application is not published on Google-Store, how I can solve this?

Comment: Publish the Android app on the Google store, or remove the Android platform from your Facebook app. I don't think there are any other options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the Android platform from the Facebook app and it worked.